# Where should I save the data of my app?

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I've just freezed with Cx_freeze a small app which works on windows. I'm aware that I can save some date in database (I'm using sqlite3). But the app needs at some point to create a folder to save drafts written by the user, and it's not working. I don't have the right to create a folder. 
[image]
The code :

```
if not os.path.exists('drafts'):
    os.makedirs('drafts')
```

It worked great when I was testing it in a folder in 'Documents', but not after freezing.
Actually, that's not really a surprise given where I'm trying to create the folder. So, I'd like to know where I should save the files (these are text files).
I'm also getting this error, with the code

```
commande = sqlite3.connect ('Base_de_donnees.db')
```

[image]
I have no ideo of why this one is not working, but it's probably linked to the first error.. 
Thanks for any enlightment

Comment: have you tired saving it somewhere to the user's home? like `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "appdir")`

Comment: I did not have any idea of what to try, so no I haven't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The User's application specific data directory is stored in the environment variable `APPDATA`.  Do something like:

```
my_app_name = 'my_app'
my_app_data_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], my_app_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to adapt it to my code it seems to work. However I can't test it freezed, because I still get the 2nd error with sqlite3, has sbdy any idea of where it comes from ?

Comment: Did you put the sqlite DB into the appdata dir? If you did, I suggest you post another question specific to sqlite.  Be sure to tag it as such.

Comment: No, it's created as in the post : `commande = sqlite3.connect ('Base_de_donnees.db')` . It worked once, and no longer now. Should I still ask another question ? Maybe it's very simple

Comment: Try to add the appdata dir onto you db file name, if that does not work, then a new question would be a good idea.

Comment: still not working.. I'm creating another question. Thanks for help !

Comment: I'm ashamed.. I had forgotten some import os.. now it works fine